# Ag-grid ag-grid-autocomplete-editor how to edit on on single click

Tags: ag-grid

I have used `https://github.com/avallete/ag-grid-autocomplete-editor` to get auto completion based on dynamic values for few columns.

I can edit a cell on double click, how can I edit a cell on single click.

Answer (score 0):

Use ag-grid [Single Click Editing](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/cell-editing-start-stop/) option.

```
singleClickEdit={true}
```

Working [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-autocomplete-editor-kvsuth?file=index.js) with autocomplete.